# Condition not being met

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements, puzzle

I am writing a small script that goes through a string and finds a given character and replaces it with another.

```
def scrambler(string):
    sen = ''
    for c in string:
        if c.lower == 'k':
            sen += 'm'
        elif c.lower == 'o':
            sen += 'q'
        elif c.lower == 'e':
            sen += 'g'
        else:
            sen += c
    return sen

print scrambler('koe')
```

As you can see if the letter is 'k' then 'm' should be added to sen. For some reason the condition is not being met but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the function object `c.lower` with a character constant: you need to *invoke* the function, instead:

```
def scrambler(string):
    sen = ''
    for c in string:
        if c.lower() == 'k':
            sen += 'm'
        elif c.lower() == 'o':
            sen += 'q'
        elif c.lower() == 'e':
            sen += 'g'
        else:
            sen += c
    return sen

print scrambler('koe')
```

Comment: thanks. How come python did not throw me any errors even though I did not include the ()?

Comment: Because `c.lower` is valid syntax, it's a reference to the function object (very, _very_ loosely, like a C function pointer): you can pass functions around, store them in variables and call. Consider this http://codepad.org/UaGkt1OU